# Error raise frequently in different part of program

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am working on a project with console app in Visual Studio 2012 (OS Windows 8). The program connects to SQL Server 2012 with a `SqlConnection` class and write some data with `SqlBulkCopy`.

Moreover, the program uses a `StreamWriter` to print results. Furthermore, the program contains some `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.Invoke`. I got this error frequently in different part of my code. I used try catch block but the program throw this error.

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I review related posts but I couldn't find any solution. I don't know it is related to my hardware. I add errors. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

[image: error message]

[image: Error message]

Comment: turn on native debugging and break on all exceptions, run under the debugger and see what the call stack looks like when its thrown.

Answer (score 0):

StreamWriter is not thread safe.  So if you are reusing the same streamwriter in different parallel blocks in it could cause an issue.

Some other pointers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx